# How do you set up a response class using Gson for this Json file?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have already tried http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to solve this but it hasn't worked. I am trying to create a Json response class for this Json format:

```
{
             "Structure1": [
              [
                    "StringValue1",
                    "StringValue2"
              ],
              [
                    "StringValue1",
                    "StringValue2"
              ]
            ],
            "Structure2": [
              [
                    "StringValue1",
                    "StringValue2"
              ]
            ],
            "Structure3": [
              [
                    "StringValue1",
                    "StringValue2"
              ]
            ]
        }
```

Here is what my current class looks like:

```
public class Response {
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();

    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setFile11Txt(HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

To parse I am doing

```
Response response = gson.fromJson(response, Response.class);
```

The returned map ends up being empty, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Buddy is your response String is comming properly

Comment: Yes that bit is fine

Comment: check my posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following code:

```
String jsonString = "{\n" +
                "             \"Structure1\": [\n" +
                "              [\n" +
                "                    \"StringValue1\",\n" +
                "                    \"StringValue2\"\n" +
                "              ],\n" +
                "              [\n" +
                "                    \"StringValue1\",\n" +
                "                    \"StringValue2\"\n" +
                "              ]\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            \"Structure2\": [\n" +
                "              [\n" +
                "                    \"StringValue1\",\n" +
                "                    \"StringValue2\"\n" +
                "              ]\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            \"Structure3\": [\n" +
                "              [\n" +
                "                    \"StringValue1\",\n" +
                "                    \"StringValue2\"\n" +
                "              ]\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "        }";

Map<String, ArrayList<String>> myMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

Debug screenshot as the following:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is an unchecked cast when converting from the raw `HashMap` type that can lead to errors here.  The type of myMap is `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>` but should be `HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>`.  Due to the use of a raw type, the compiler does not catch the type mismatch until you try to access the myMap.  For instance, `List<String> structure1List = myMap.get("Structure1").get(0);` will fail to compile.

Comment: @noobcode: please accept iagreen's answer instead of mine, then I will delete my answer here :)

Comment: Although we can use `List<?> structure1List = myMap.get("Structure1");
        ArrayList<String> arrayString = (ArrayList<String>) structure1List.get(1);` however it causes another uncheck cast :)

Comment: Exactly.  If you switched the type of `myMap` to `HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>` in your answer, it would probably work for the noobcoder's needs without throwing an exception since it is the expected type.  Deserializing to the generic type (HashMap in this case) causes a loss of type information, so the programmer has to manage that himself.  If you keep everything in order, you should fine, but if you are able to use stronger typing you can catch some of the errors at compile time instead of runtime because the compiler can double check your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Response` represents and object that contains a `HashMap` in a field named `map`, but your JSON represents just a `Map`.  You do not need to have an enclosing object, just deserialize the `HashMap` directly --

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> map;
Type mapType = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>>() {}.getType();
map = gson.fromJson(response, mapType);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeToken objtype= new TypeToken<Response>() {}.getType();
Response responseobj= new Gson().fromJson(responsestring, objtype);

use Typetoken to parse Gson Object back to original one
```

Comment: My map is still empty, I suspect the problem is to do with the Response class